# Is there a way to do some pre-process/post-process every time I call a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number of calls I need to make to functions imported from a package (the package is a shared object file). However I need to do some pre-process / post - process step every time I make a call to a function from this package. Something like this:

```
import xyz

prepare()
xyz.foo(<args>)
done()

prepare()
xyz.bar(<args>)
done()

prepare()
xyz.foobar()
done()
```

Is there some way I can ask python to always invoke `prepare()` before I call a function from `xyz` module. And also to invoke `done()` after the call is complete?
Writing `prepare` and `done` through my whole code seems redundant and messy. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically done with a context manager.

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def with_preparation():
    prepare()
    yield
    done()

with preparation():
    xyz.foo(<args>)

with preparation():
    xyz.bar(<args>)

with preparation():
    xyz.foobar()
```

`preparation` defines a function that returns a *context manager*. The `with` statement works by invoking the context manager's `__enter__` method, then executing the body, then ensuring that the context manager's `__exit__` method is invoked before moving on (whether due to an exception being raised or the body completing normally).

`contextlib.contextmanager` provides a simple way to define a context manager using a generator function, rather than making you define a class with explicit `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

---

You mentioned you need this for every function in a particular module. Without exact details about the module, this may not be entirely correct, but you  might be able to build up on it.

```
class XYZWrapper:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # Intentionally let an AttributeError propagate upwards
        f = getattr(xyz, name)
        def _(self, *args, **kwargs):
            prepare()
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
            done()
        setattr(XYZWrapper, name, _)
        return _

prepared = XYZWrapper()

prepared.foo(<args>)
prepared.bar(<args>)
prepared.foobar()
```

In short, any attribute access on the `XYZWrapper` instance tries to find an identical attribute on the `xyz` module, and if successful, defines a wrapper that calls `prepare()` and `done()` as needed and patches the `XYZWrapper` instance with the new wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @chepner! This sounds like a good idea. However still I have to use with statements for any calls to `xyz` module. Nonetheless, far better that what i was initially planning to do.

Comment: You don't want to make things *too* implicit. You only have to write the code once; better to make the intent and effect of the code clear for future readers (which includes you a week from now).

Comment: Thanks @chepner! agree with you - hidden magic isn't a great idea.

Comment: However, if it's *every* function from the module, you might want to define a class that maps each function to a method that handles the pre/post processing. Something like `preparer = XYZWrapper(); preparer.foo(...)  # equivalent to prepare(); xyz.foo(); done()`.

Comment: thats a good thought - but this `package` has several 100 functions, and I don't want to go about writing a wrapper for each function (taking care of appropriate args for each one). I will go with the `context_manager` approach.

Comment: I added an attempt to write a module wrapper that generates and caches wrapper methods on demand.

Answer (score 2):

To extend [@chepner's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71268944/843953), you can define your own class and use its `__getattr__` function to create a function that wraps the actual module's function with your pre- and post-processing functions:

```
import typing
import xyz

def XYZWrapper():
    def __init__(self, pre, post):
        self.pre = pre
        self.post = post

    def __getattr__(self, a):
        func = getattr(xyz, a)
        if isinstance(func, typing.Callable):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                self.pre()
                func(*args, **kwargs)
                self.post()
            return wrapper
        raise TypeError(f"'{type(func)}' object is not callable")
```

To use it, do

```
xyz = XYZWrapper(prepare, done)
xyz.foo(<args>)
...
```

Note that if you want to overwrite the `xyz` variable, you will need to put the wrapper class in a separate file.

Comment: Thanks! I will stick with the contextmanager. But appreciate these other ways of doing the same!